# Doubt concerning certain Extension groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kazhdan-lusztig

I am reading the paper **["Categories Of Highest Weight Modules: Applications To Classical Hermitian Symmetric Pairs"](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=888703)**

I do NOT understand why Proposition 14.4 implies Theorem 14.9.

[image]

[image]

Now let us use the notation in **Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$:**

Let $\Phi$ be a root system with a base $\Delta$ and the corresponding positive system $\Phi^+$, $I\subseteq \Delta$, $\Phi_I$ be the root system generated by $I$ and $\Phi_I^+=\Phi_I\cap\Phi^+$.
Let $W^I=\{w\in W: w^{-1}\Phi_I^+\subseteq \Phi^+\}$, $W_I$ be the parabolic subgroup generated by $I$ and $w_I$ be the longest element in $W_I$. Let $M(\eta)$, $M_I(\eta)$ be the Verma module with weight $\eta$ and the parabolic Verma module with weight $\eta$, respectively. Let $L(\eta)$ be the unique simple quotient of both of them. Let $\le $ be the Bruhat order on $W$. Let $\rho$ be the half sum of positive roots in $\Phi^+$.

> Part (b) of proposition 14.4 can be restated as:
>   Let $y,w\in W^I$.
>
> For any $j$, $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(w_Iy\cdot(-2\rho)),L(w_Iw\cdot(-2\rho)))=0$ unless $y\le w$ and $j\equiv \ell(y)-\ell(w)\ \text{mod }2$
>
> How can this show: **If $\ell(y)<\ell(w)$, then $\mathrm{Ext}^j_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(w_Iy\cdot(-2\rho)),L(w_Iw\cdot(-2\rho)))=0$ for all $j$**?

In my opinion, I think the assertion "**If $\ell(y)<\ell(w)$, then $\mathrm{Ext}^j_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(w_Iy\cdot(-2\rho)),L(w_Iw\cdot(-2\rho)))=0$ for all $j$**" is WRONG.

Here is my argument to show it is wrong:

Let $P_{u,v}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of $u,v\in W$.
It is well-known that $P_{w_Ie,w_Iw}(q)$ has constant term 1 for $e<w$ (in which $\ell(e)<\ell(w)$). By the relationship between Ext groups and Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial, there exists some $r$, $\mathrm{Ext}^r_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(w_Ie\cdot(-2\rho)),L(w_Iw\cdot(-2\rho)))\cong \mathrm{Ext}^r_{\mathcal{O}}(M(w_Ie\cdot(-2\rho)),L(w_Iw\cdot(-2\rho)))\neq 0$.

> Did I miss something? Does the proof of Theorem 14.9 wrong? Is my argument correct?

Comment: I do not have an answer, but from my experience, this book has many problems... :)

Comment: @James: Strictly speaking, the Enright-Shelton paper you quote is not a "book" but rather a long paper.  The series of "AMS Memoirs" tends to overlap the journal "AMS Transactions", especially in the age of LaTeX. But the Memoirs do get their own Library of Congress numbers, etc. Anyway it's hard to draw a line.

Comment: @James: Also, it's probably simplest to use a format  <a href="https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=888703"> *here* </a>.